# Pycord - Cogs Error: Extension 'cogs.Fun' has no 'setup' function

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I have my code in a single file, and i'm trying to organize the commands using Cogs, but i keep on getting the same error everytime `Extension 'cogs.Fun' has no 'setup' function.`

**MAIN FILE CODE:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
import os
import asyncio

intents = Intents.all()
intents.members = True




bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We Have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Fun.py Cog CODE:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents

intents = Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

class Fun(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Fun(bot))
```

**FULL ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\HypePartyBOT\test5.py", line 29, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "e:\HypePartyBOT\test5.py", line 26, in main
    await load()
  File "e:\HypePartyBOT\test5.py", line 23, in load
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\cog.py", line 893, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\cog.py", line 766, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.NoEntryPointError(key)
discord.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.Fun' has no 'setup' function.
```

Please note that i also have tried to align the setup to `__init__`, and `await` it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should edit the post asap and remove your token, and then you should probably get a new token as you have now just posted it for everyone to see on the internet. As for your issue, try this instead:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Intents
import os

intents = Intents.all()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We Have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Thank you i didn't notice i posted the token, for the code i'm still having the same issue, it still gives the same error.

Comment: Hmm that's odd, are you 100% certain that there is only one Fun.py file in the cogs folder?

Comment: It is indeed, yes, also i would to mention that some cogs works but when i add more to the file it gives the error

Comment: try loading the cog without the for loop, with just `bot.load_extension("cogs.Fun")` no matter what I do I cannot recreate the issue, do you know what version of python you are using?